# When will a minified version of MicrosoftMvcAjax.js be available?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cdn, microsoft-ajax

I have been running YSlow against my site and the Microsoft Ajax files are quite hefty:

http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/3.5/MicrosoftAjax.js = 99.3k

and

http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/mvc/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js = 136.7k

Is there likely to be a minified version of these files on the Microsoft CDN soon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/3.5/MicrosoftAjax.js  is already minified... if you look at the code.

the only way that its going to do better if they gzip them ... which they do for certain browsers...

http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/mvc/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js  is coming up as a 404

http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/mvc/1.0/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js is the correct address and is minified as well...

I get that MVCAjax is 4.3 KB (when saved to disk) and MVCAjaxDebug is 12 KB ....

...I know you are looking for performance but I think this might be a dry well.

-Mark

Comment: MVCAjax  is 2.06 KB when downloaded via IE

Comment: Change the code to reference mvc/1.0 and I'm getting the 4.8k in YSlow Components breakdown, the 404 must be 136.7 ;->

Answer (score 1):

You can minify the files yourself [here.](http://www.minifyjavascript.com/)

Comment: Just realised this isn't what your looking for!

Comment: If they will not be available soon I might have to do this!